# Spring Integration JDBC inbound channel adapter not updating records

Tags: spring-integration

The application context of my Spring Boot application is:

```
<context:component-scan
base-package="org.mycompany.myproject.polling" />

<int:channel id="fromdb" />
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="fromdb" ref="jdbcMessageHandler" />
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="fromdb" data-source="dataSource"
    query="select * from Books where status = 0"
    update="update Books set status = 1">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have schema.sql and data.sql in the resources directory that create the table and insert data on startup with all records in the status column having value 0. The update query of the inbound channel adapter does not run, since I see that status column in H2 still has value 0.

What did I miss?

Comment: Maybe the rollback nature of the test Framework by default?

Comment: I have not written any test code. The ApplicationTests class just has an empty contextLoads method.
I just run `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: Turn on, please, DEBUG logging for the `org.springframework.jdbc` category to investigate what and how is called against your DB. Not sure though how you can check the state of the embedded DB if you run your app via Maven...

Comment: I have spring-boot-starter-web dependency in pom.xml and spring.h2.console.enabled=true in application.properties. I check the DB at localhost:8080/h2-console/
Though I added DEBUG logging, I am still not getting any help from the messages.

Comment: OK! Any chance to have a simple Spring Boot project from your side to let us to play with that locally to understand the problem? Thanks

Comment: Could you please access this --
http://www.mediafire.com/file/cv6edue081eetqh/dbpoller.zip

Comment: I got it. Will come back to you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application works for me well after this simple modifications:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("application-context.xml")
public class DbpollerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DbpollerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

As you see I removed suspicious code for the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`  and really let Spring Boot to load everything, including Embedded DataSource.

In the `application-context.xml` I removed `<context:component-scan>` and `<jdbc:embedded-database>` just because they are supplied by the Spring Boot per se.

After starting application I see in logs:

```
Row
column: ITEM_ID value: Book_id99
column: DESCRIPTION value: Book_description99
column: STATUS value: 0
Row
column: ITEM_ID value: XXX
column: DESCRIPTION value: last book
column: STATUS value: 0
```

And also I've copied from there and URL to the DB:

```
2018-02-21 16:49:40.357  INFO 10576 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

The part `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` is just enough.

Then I've opened H2 Web console on the `localhost:8080/h2-console`, connected to the mentioned URL and did a `SELECT` from the `BOOKS` table and got this result:

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Great help, thanks. Looks like the problem line `<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" /> ` re-creates the database and/or re-runs the startup data.sql after the adapter code runs.